# How CallableStatement in Oracle Works?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

I need to know whether Oracle CallableStatement makes a DB call to compile ( or bind) IN/OUT parameters in the stored procedure?

If the answer is yes, what is the request sent by the JDBC driver to DB?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but maybe this will help.

OracleConnection.prepareCall does not make a database round trip.

OracleCallableStatement.setXXX does not make a database round trip.

OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter does not make a database round trip.

The only method on OracleCallableStatement that always makes database round trips is execute.

OracleCallableStatement.getXXX may make a database round trip. Mostly this depends on the type of the OUT parameter. If the OUT parameter is an ARRAY, STRUCT, REF, or OPAQUE there may be a database round trip if the driver has not yet seen the type description for the type. Type descriptions are cached by the connection so once the driver has retrieved the type description it will not have to do a database round trip to construct an instance of the type. Calling getString or getBytes (or some other getXXX that needs the complete value) on a BLOB, CLOB, NCLOB, or BFILE type may require a database round trip if the entire value was not retrieved in the initial call. Calling getBlob, getClob, getNClob or getBfile (as appropriate) on a BLOB, CLOB, NCLOB, or BFILE out parameter does not do a database round trip.